# How can I use a regex to tell if a string has 10 digits?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need to find a regex that tests that an input string contains exactly 10 numeric characters, while still allowing other characters in the string.

I'll be stripping all of the non-numeric characters in post processing, but I need the regex for client-side validation.

For example, these should all match:

- 1234567890
- 12-456879x54
- 321225 -1234AAAA
- xx1234567890

But these should not:

- 123456789   (not enough digits)
- 12345678901 (too many digits)

This seems like it should be very simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/^\D*(\d\D*){10}$/
```

Basically, match any number of non-digit characters, followed by a digit followed by any number of non-digit characters, exactly 10 times.

Comment: Thanks.  This works for my test cases, but I confess that I don't understand it.  I understand that \D is non-numeric, and \d is numeric, ^ and $ are the start and end, respectively, and that {10} says exactly 10 times.  So, while I get all of the symbology, I just don't get the magic behind the curtain.  I see some other comments here about matching across multi-lines, but since I'm validating a single-line textbox, this one will do the job.

Comment: Actually, I just read the description you'd already written.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: For this specific example... is the `^` needed? It's supposed to match the start of the String... but, what's the real purpose of it? either leaving it or removing it the expression matches the String, so, what's the purpose of adding it?

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona its purpose is to make sure there are not too many digits

Answer (score 0):

May be a simpler way, but this should do it.

```
/^([^\d]*\d){10}[^\d]*$/
```

Though the regex gets easier to handle if you first strip out all non-numeric characters then test on the result. Then it's a simple

```
/^\d{10}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\D*(\d\D*){10}\D*$
```

Comment: The extra `\D*` on the end is unnecessary. Anything non-digit at the end will get picked up as part of the 10th capture group.